# How to reloop the game and ask something

Tags: c#

I made a program that calculates the temperature in different ways.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Excercise_7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            showBegin();
            decide();   
            secondPlay();
            showEnd();

        }
    // Decide code
    static void decide() {
        int choice;
        string input;
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        int.TryParse(input, out choice);
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            celciusSystem();
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            farenheitSystem();
        }
        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            kelvinSystem();
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Make sure u write a number between 1 and 3! No text!");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            showBegin();
            decide();
        }
    }
    static void secondPlay()
    {
        int choice2;
        string input;
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Type 1 to play again, type 2 to close the application");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        int.TryParse(input, out choice2);

    }

    // Begin code
    static void showBegin()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcom at the temperature calculator, pick the mode u prefer!");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for Celcius mode");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 2 for Fahrenheit mode");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 3 for Kelvin mode");
        Console.WriteLine("Press the correct number and then hit the enter button!");
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
    // Temperature Calculators
    static void celciusSystem()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is the Celsius calculator");
        Console.Write("Enter the amount of celsius: ");

        int celsius = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("The temperature in Kelvin = {0}", celsius + 273);
        Console.WriteLine("The temperature in Fahrenheit = {0}", celsius * 18 / 10 + 32);

    }
    static void farenheitSystem()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is the Fahrenheit calculator");
        Console.Write("Enter the amount of Fahrenheit: ");

        int Fahrenheit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("The temperature in Kelvin = {0}", (Fahrenheit + 459.67) / 1.8);
        Console.WriteLine("The temperature in Celsius = {0}", (Fahrenheit - 32) / 1.8);

    }

    static void kelvinSystem()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is the Kelvin calculator");
        Console.Write("Enter the amount of Kelvin: ");

        int Kelvin = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("The temperature in Fahrenheit = {0}", Kelvin * 1.8 - 459.67);
        Console.WriteLine("The temperature in Celsius = {0}", Kelvin - 273.15);

    }
    // End code
    static void showEnd()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("We hoped u enjoyed our application!");
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


}
}
```

So now my question, I made a class called second play. Within that class i tried to make a kind a statement that would ask the user if he or she wanted to "play" again. So if they write 1 he should loop the game again.

I have tried it with this

```
  if (choice2 == 1)
        {
            while (choice2 == 1) {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                showBegin();
                decide();
            }

        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Cheers!!");
        }
    }
```

then he actually worked but not the way I wanted to because if the user writes 1 it will loop the first thing all over again. So the user can't quit the game any more.

I want the application to ask after every trail if he or she wants to play again by typing 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know how to read lines from the console, you also know how to use `if` to compare booleans, so why don't you just apply this and check if they wrote a 1 or 2?

```
private bool playAgain()
{
    int number = 2; //Invalid option: close game
    Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number);
    if (number == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (number == 2)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unknown option, quitting!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you just have to use that function to determine if they want to play again in a [do-loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    showBegin(); //Show begin sequence
    do
    {
    decide();   
    secondPlay();
    } while(playAgain()); //Play again if they want to
    showEnd(); //Show end sequence when they decided not to play

}
```

*Pro tip: use a [switch-case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.asp) statement instead of multiple `if-else` statements.*

Comment: It sadly doesnt work when I applied this part of the code it does the loop but it doesnt ask the question after every attempt they do.

Comment: Yes, because if you just copy-pasted my code, you should've seen i never put a `Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play again?");` anywhere! Put it at the start of the `playAgain()` function. @D.R

Comment: I didnt just copy past it ;) But if I use your code my secondPlay will be useless and besides that it will give me a error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.playAgain()'

Comment: Change `public bool` to `public static bool` then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `do while` loop, which serves you well in cases like yours, when you want to execute your loop at least once:

```
do {
    Console.WriteLine("");
    showBegin();
    decide();
    //Ask for choice2 here
}
while(choice2 == 1);

Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("Cheers!!");
```

Comment: Its still in a loop where he doesnt ask if he wants to play again after every trail https://gyazo.com/2ac9821c698f225ddea4629ebd6d9960

Comment: You must be asking for `choice2` somewhere before the `if` in your code. That part goes to where I write `//Ask for choice2 here`.

Answer (score 0):

To enter game loop, it is most useful to start with simple `while` or `do-while`.

```
while( conditionToRun )
{
   //run the program
   if( userWantToExit )
     conditionToRun = false;
}
```

Or

```
do
{
    // run the program
} while ( !userWantToExit )
```

This code shows the most basic stuff to handle this.

To apply on Your game/program, use:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     bool userWantToEnd = false;

     showBegin();  

     while( !userWantToEnd)
     {
         decide();   
         userWantToEnd = IsUserWillingToContinue();
     }

     showEnd();

 }
```

And adjust the `SecondPlay()` method into something like `IsUserWillingToContinue()`:

```
public bool IsUserWillingToContinue()
{
    int choice2;
    string input;
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Type 1 to play again, type 2 to close the application");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
    int.TryParse(input, out choice2);

    return choice2 == 1;
}
```

Adding more info based on comment of @devRicher - You should split up a bit the code so it work in this way

```
bool runAgain = true;

Console.WriteLine("Begin info: (Hello this is XY game.)");
while(runAgain)
{
     Console.WriteLine("You have 3 options: 1, 2, 3");
     PickOptionAndRunTheCode();

     bool runAgain = DoYouWantToContinue();
     Console.Clear(); // clear the Console screen (next time You will see only options, not the text on first run).
}
```

I would recommend to get more knowledge about games to go to this page -> http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/ (and read the book)

Check this pattern: [Game Loop](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html)

Comment: You cannot use a while loop, as it would ask the user if they want to play again before they even played once.